# What is the process to be nominated for the Man Booker Prize?

Tags: awards, booker-prize

The [Man Booker Prize](http://themanbookerprize.com/) is often cited as one of the most prestigious awards for English literature. The selection process is supposed to be highly rigorous.

But what's the process to be nominated for the prize. Surely, no one can just submit a nomination just like that. What's the process for being nominated?

Answer (score 7):

**Nominations must be made by the publisher, and there are many restrictions on eligibility.**

You can find the rules at the Man* Booker Prize website [here](http://themanbookerprize.com/submissions), with specific rules for the English Man Booker Prize (for books originally written in English) and the International Man Booker Prize (for books translated from other languages) available as PDF files [here](http://themanbookerprize.com/sites/manbosamjo/files/uploadedfiles/files/161208%20MB2017%20Rules%20And%20Entry%20Form%20FINAL.pdf) and [here](http://themanbookerprize.com/sites/manbosamjo/files/uploadedfiles/files/160802%20MBI2017%20Rules%20And%20Entry%20Form%20REVISED%20-%20USE.pdf).

For the **English-language** Man Booker Prize:

> The judges are responsible for compiling a longlist of 12 or 13 books – ‘The Man Booker Dozen’ – and from this a shortlist of six books from which they then choose the winner.
>
> Each shortlisted author receives £2,500 and a designer bound copy of his or her novel.
>
> The winning author receives a further £50,000.
>
> The prize may not be divided or withheld.
>
> **Publishers’ entry quotas**
>
> Novels to be considered by the judges can only be submitted by the 
>   publishers identified in 1a. below. The number of novels a publisher can 
>   submit will depend on that publisher’s inclusion in longlists from 2012 
>   to 2016, as follows:
>
> - 1 submission - publishers with no longlisting
> - 2 submissions - publishers with 1 or 2 longlisting(s)
> - 3 submissions - publishers with 3 or 4 longlistings
> - 4 submissions - publishers with 5 or more longlistings
>
> Please see the last page for the 2011 to 2015 longlists.

For the **International** Man Booker Prize:

> The judges read the submissions and are responsible for compiling a 
>   longlist of 12 or 13 books, and from this a shortlist of six books from which 
>   they then choose a winner.
>
> The winner's prize purse is £50,000 divided equally between the author and the translator. There will be a prize of £2,000 each of the shortlisted titles divided equally between the author and the translator.
>
> The prize may not be divided or withheld.
>
> There is no restriction on the number of submissions per publisher but this 
>   will be kept under review and may change in future years.

In both cases, there are also several pages of regulations governing which books and publishers are eligible, the form the submission has to take, etc. For obvious reasons I'm not going to copy and paste all of this here, but I will note the following paragraph (`1j`) which appears in both documents:

> The decision of the Administrator of the prize as to whether a work is eligible shall be final and binding and no correspondence will be entered into.

*The Man Group ended their sponsorship of the prize in 2019. From 2020 onwards the prize will revert to being The Booker Prize.